# AWS SNS Topic Policy Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

Trying to create an SNS topic using cloud formation script. It all works fine, except the topic policy.

This is what we get by default,

[image]

I want to update the policy as below using cloud formation script.

[image]
Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As was pointed out in one of the comments, you don't want to use AWS:* as a principal since it grants anyone with an AWS account access.

To create a SNS topic, and restrict access to certain services, or anyone in the account, use the following example.

The "AllowServices" SID show how to add multiple services, while the AllowAWS allows anything in the account to access it.

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Parameters:
  Email:
    Type: String
    Default: <your name here>

Resources:
  Topic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      TopicName: TestTopic
      Subscription:
      - Endpoint: !Ref Email
        Protocol: email

  TopicPolicy:
    Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Sid: AllowServices
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - events.amazonaws.com
                - cloudwatch.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sns:Publish'
            Resource:
              - !Ref Topic
          - Sid: AllowAWS
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root"
            Action: 'sns:Publish'
            Resource:
              - !Ref Topic
      Topics:
        - !Ref Topic
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you need a AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy resource.  Check out this link [AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-iam.html#scenario-sns-policy)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this- i've removed the default condition which locks down own account

```
SNSAccessPolicy:
    Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
    Properties:
     PolicyDocument:
       Id: <Yourtopic>
       Statement:
         -
           Action: 
            - "sns:Publish"
            - "SNS:GetTopicAttributes"
            - "SNS:SetTopicAttributes"
            - "SNS:AddPermission"
            - "SNS:RemovePermission"
            - "SNS:DeleteTopic"
            - "SNS:Subscribe"
            - "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic"
            - "SNS:Publish"
            - "SNS:Receive"
           Effect: Allow
           Principal:
             AWS: "*"
           Resource:
             Ref: <Yourtopic>
     Topics:
       -
         Ref: <Yourtopic>
```

Comment: Do not use this - it grants anyone with your SNS arn the ability to delete, modify, etc.

Comment: I used this for my use case which required only "sns:Publish" permission for the events service

Comment: As @MattMcCann said don't use this. More specifically never use 'AWS: "*"' unless for some reason you wish to give everyone in AWS access. This is almost always a bad idea.